How to save emails sent via Mailkit on the server?
I'm using the MailKit library to make a simple WPF app to send automatic emails.
I hired hosting that uses Cpanel to create emails with Roundcube, where I am using the information to connect, log in, etc.
When I manually logged into Roundcube, I noticed that the test emails I sent were not in the sent folder.
I can send emails perfectly with the following code:
public static async Task SendMail(BilletInfo info, string m)
{
    try
    {
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(Server.Name, Server.Login));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(info.ClientName, info.Mail));
        message.Subject = MessageController.GetChargeTitle(info);

        var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
        bodyBuilder.TextBody = m;
        bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(info.AttachmentPath);

        message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

        using(var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect(Server.ServerName, Server.SMTPPort, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
            client.Authenticate(Server.Login, Server.Password);

            await client.SendAsync(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBoxController.ShowError($ "{ex.Message}");
    }
}

However, it does not appear in the Roundcube client.
Is there any way to save messages sent by MailKit on the server in a way that appears in the Roundcube client?

You'll need to use the ImapClient to save the message to an IMAP "Sent" folder.
using (var client = new ImapClient()) {
    client.Connect(host, port, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
    client.Authenticate(username, password);

    // Hopefully your server supports the SPECIAL-USE or XLIST extensions
    // to make getting the Sent folder easy.
    IMailFolder sent = null;

    if (client.Capabilities.HasFlag(ImapCapabilities.SpecialUse) ||
        client.Capabilities.HasFlag(ImapCapabilities.XList)) {
        sent = client.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.Sent);
    }

    if (sent == null) {
        var personal = client.GetFolder(client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
        sent = personal.GetSubfolders().FirstOrDefault(subfolder => subfolder.Name.StartsWith("Sent"));
    }

    sent?.Append(message);

    client.Disconnect(true);
}

